# Rails / Chrome / Heroku Favicon Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, favicon

I can't seem to get a favicon to show up on my site when using Chrome. Locally, the favicon works fine but after pushing to Heroku somehow it loads Google's favicon.

Firefox displays the correct icon in both cases.

My head tag has this line:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
```

Which produces this on localhost:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
```

And on Heroku:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicon-7b525a3805f8dcadf5aae8526d1417e8.ico">
```

My icon is stored at `/app/assets/images/favicon.ico`. I've deleted the default `/public/favicon.ico`.

My versions:

- Rails: `5.0.0.alpha` (but happens on 4 as well)
- Chrome: `40.0.2214.94 (64-bit)`
- Firefox: `35.0.1`
- Heroku: cedar-14 stack

I've looked at other similar questions and none of the solutions help. I'm guessing this has something to do with asset compilation. Has anyone experienced this?

Edit: The browser is successfully loading the favicon resource (I can open `/assets/favicon-7b525a3805f8dcadf5aae8526d1417e8.ico` in another tab). It just isn't being used as an actual favicon.

Comment: Are you load the favicon in a separate chrome tab (site.com/assets/favicon-7b525a3805f8dcadf5aae8526d1417e8.ico)?

Comment: Yes it loads fine that way.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Heroku account and bring up your application. Pull down the More menu and click <kbd>Run Console</kbd> See if your graphic appears in the Heroku directories (I use `app/assets/images`).  If it isn't there, you need to use a git command to add it.

On your computer, use `git add` followed by the favicon filename (with an appropriate path, such as `app/assets/images`). Perform a push (use `git push` as usual) and see if the favicon appears now!